# How to add user with dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How can I add a user with Dockerfile - the following does not work.

```
USER vault
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/vault
```

My full Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk update && apk add curl unzip
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash vault

USER vault
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/vault
ADD /vault.hcl /etc/vault/vault.hcl

RUN curl -SL https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.5.0/vault_0.5.0_linux_amd64.zip > vault.zip
RUN unzip vault.zip -d /usr/local/bin && rm vault.zip
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `useradd` instead of its interactive `adduser` to add user.

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash  vault
```

Below command will not create user .

```
USER vault
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/vault
```

it will use `vault` user

please Refer [Dockerfile User Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

> The USER instruction sets the user name or UID to use when running the
>   image and for any RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions that follow it
>   in the Dockerfile.

**NOTE :** Ensures that `bash` is the default shell.

If default shell is `/bin/sh` you can do like:

```
RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash  vault
```

Comment: Show your Dockerfile, and the line `FROM`

Comment: `FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk update && apk add curl unzip 


RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash vault
USER vault
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/vault

ADD /vault.hcl /etc/vault/vault.hcl
RUN curl -SL https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.5.0/vault_0.5.0_linux_amd64.zip > vault.zip
RUN unzip vault.zip -d /usr/local/bin && rm vault.zip`

Comment: try last part of my answer

Comment: `useradd` command is not present in your base image `alpine`. i don't know about this image but this will run in ubuntu, centos etc. images.  i tested using `FROM ubuntu:14.04` . do google about alpine useradd command

Comment: If You use alpine You must user addgroup and adduser

`RUN addgroup -g ${GROUPID} -S ${USERNAME}`
`RUN adduser -S -G ${USERNAME} -u ${USERID} -s /bin/bash -h ${USER_HOME} ${USERNAME}`

Comment: I have an issue where if I don't specify the user id useradd will just start assigning uid from 1000 which will clash with already existing host users.

Comment: I get the following error:  /bin/sh: useradd: not found

Answer (score 8):

To add group and to associate a new user, use code below.

```
FROM <base image>
RUN groupadd -g 2000 go \
&& useradd -m -u 2001 -g go go
USER go
```

OR

```
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S appuser && adduser -u 1001 -S appuser  -G appuser
```

Comment: When I follow these steps while using the  selenium docker image as the base image, the build is successful but when I run my image, it says
groupadd: GID 2000 already exists. I have tried for different IDs and the same error persists. Is there any way I could resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the selenium docker image are you using?

Comment: elgalu/selenium:latest

Comment: Hi Amith,

I couldn't reproduce this error!

Just to test, try **centos:7** image. You will see these steps work are working well.

When I put elgalu/selenium:latest, I have recieve the message 

"groupadd: Permission denied.
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later."

This happens because just root user is able to create new user

Comment: This would be better if group and name weren't the same, so one can read the signature of the useradd command easily

Comment: -S is ambigous (shell or system)

Answer (score 6):

If you also want your user to have a password, use this for Alpine based-images:

```
FROM alpine
ARG USER=usernameThatYouWant
ARG PASS="some password"
RUN adduser -D $USER && echo "$USER:$PASS" | chpasswd
```

- The `ARG` lines are there so you can (optionally) choose another username and password when building the image (without having to change the Dockerfile).
- `-D` so that `adduser` doesn't set a password just yet.
  *Without this option `adduser` would become interactive and ask for a password. It doesn't accept this from the regular STDIN, so piping the password is also not an option.*
- `echo "$USER:$PASS" | chpasswd` to finally set the password.
- Note that I do not set a shell with `-s /path/to/some/shell` in `adduser` because Alpine only has `ash` and `sh` available. Both of these are just symlinks to `busybox` anyway.
  *(But if you are going to install another shell in your image you probably do want to use it.)*

For Ubuntu-based images use this:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG USER=usernameThatYouWant
ARG PASS="some password"
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash $USER && echo "$USER:$PASS" | chpasswd
```

I am using:

- `useradd` because here this is the program for non-interactive usage.
- `-m` so that we the user has a homedir.
- `-s /bin/bash` so that the user has bash as default shell.

(For most other base-images you will also need to use the Ubuntu-method )