# How to change from ROOT ownership to jenkins after build of the Jenkins-job inside docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I have build step in my jenkins-pipeline:

```
        stage('Build') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'mymvnbasedimage:latest'
                args '-u root:root'
                reuseNode true
            }
        }
        steps {
                sh "ant"
            }
        }
```

It works, everything is fine. But, then the `workspace` will contains directory and files owned by `root` which can not be deleted by the user `jenkins` at the next run when cleaning the `workpace`.

```
ls -lt ~/workspace/myjenkinsjob/dist/
total 185764
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190218240 Aug  3 19:49 buildresult-21.tar
```

O f course i can add:

```
        stage('Chown to user Jenkins'){
            steps {
            echo 'Chown to user Jenkins'
            sh "sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins ${WORKSPACE}"
            }
        }
```

But it is not ok, because i have to add in the `/etc/sudoers` rights to make `chown` for user `Jenkins`. Also, i can't make inside container operation of `chown`, because there user `jenkins` does not exists. Which variant, you can advice ? Please help.

Comment: Don’t chown by the username inside the container but the PID instead.

Comment: @emix sorry ? can You explain more please ?

Comment: UID not PID sorry :) check it with `id -u your_username` then in the container if the result was `1000`: `chown 1000:1000 -R ${WORKSPACE}`. You could also pass the UID as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest to Set ${WORKSPACE} as a volume with a folder on the host and set appropriate rights for jenkins on the host folder using jenkins user uid. uid user on host should be equals to uid in docker container.

Comment: can you explain how to do this technically ? i am already using workspace `reuseNode true`

Comment: I misunderstood your question. can you create a user in you image mymvnbasedimage:latest ?

If yes, create a jenkins user in your image (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855304/how-to-add-user-with-dockerfile/39855387) with the same uid as the real jenkins user (grep jenkins /etc/passwd) 

Then chown with your jenkins uid

Answer (score 0):

I have used a next Kludge

```
script {
    def jUserID = sh returnStdout: true, script: "id -u"
    jUserID = jUserID.trim()
    def jGroupID = sh returnStdout: true, script: "id -g"
    jGroupID = jGroupID.trim()
    sh "docker run --rm -v ./src:/src bash chown -R ${jUserID}:${jGroupID} /src/FOLDER_TO_CHOWN"
}
```

Also, I have been looking into involving docker via the plugin as a standalone stage, something like

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'bash'
        reuseNode true
    }
}
steps {
    sh 'chown -R ${jUserID}:${jGroupID} /code/FOLDER_TO_CHOWN'
}
```

But I have no idea how to define a variable in this case and even more, how to substitute it in the command. At least while writing this answer )